# Can a Xamarin / C# / Android app easily talk to a local Oracle Server?

Tags: c#, android, oracle, xamarin

Using Visual Studio 2017 / Xamarin with C# in an Android app, can the app easily talk to an Oracle Server running on our local Windows domain? And can this be done with freely available drivers? Or is a 3rd party driver required?

Currently, my company develops Windows apps on Visual Studio 2013. Connecting to Oracle using the Oracle native .NET driver is very easy. But we are looking to develop some apps to run on a handheld barcode scanner running Android. Before we make the investment in VS 2017 and the Android devices, we would like to be sure it is technically feasible.